# Apache and mod_mono - only serves HTML files

Tags: apache2, mono

I have tried to set up an Ubuntu server running Apache/mod_mono in a VirtualBox VM, and have encountered a problem when trying to configure Apache to use mod_mono to serve the ASP.NET application.

I got a dummy ASP.NET application in `/var/www/aspx1` (a simple `Default.aspx` and a minimalistic `Web.config`). Here is my `httpd.conf` file:

```
ServerName localhost
Include mod_mono.conf
```

And my `mod_mono.conf`:

```
<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
    LoadModule mono_module modules/mod_mono.so

    MonoAutoApplication enabled

    AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
    AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
    AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
    AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
    AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
    AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
    AddType application/x-asp-net .master
    AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
    AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
    AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
    AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
    AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
    AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
    AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
    AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
    AddType application/x-asp-net .config
    AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
    AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
    DirectoryIndex index.aspx
    DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
    DirectoryIndex default.aspx
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried to disable `MonoAutoApplication` and add the following lines:

```
AddMonoApplications default "/:/var/www"
<Location "/">
    SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

Going to `http://int.er.nal.ip/aspx1/` simply lists the folder contents (Apache standard listing) and going to `http://int.er.nal.ip/aspx1/Default.aspx` offers to save the file.

After every change I have restarted Apache, and also rebooted the VM just in case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely not the optimal solution, but commenting the first and last lines seems to solve the problem. I do get a warning on double-loading, but now I know that with those lines the file isn't even read.